# C#: why is there an asterisk on one of the code editor tabs in VS2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, code-editor

C#: why is there an asterisk on one of the code editor tabs in VS2005?

Does it have something to do with source control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the file has been modified, but not saved.  When you save the tab (file), the asterisk will go away.

This has nothing to do with source control.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it answered the part about source control.

Answer (score 11):

It means there are unsaved modifications.

Press CTRL+s to save and it'll go away.

Answer (score 5):

As the others said, it means unsaved changes. If you're not sure what you changed in the file, scroll down looking for yellow bars in the margin - they indicate lines with unsaved changes. Green bars mean lines with saved changes.